# What would be the best video player similar to YouTube?

Tags: video, media-player

I am so used to the YouTube player and I'm mainly looking for a player that merely uses the same functions and shortcuts as YouTube and **must** have an option to modify the playback speed.
The OS should be Windows 10 and it should be free (as most of this *basic* types of software are)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should it run on, how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid software, what features do you need?

Answer (score 0):

[Free Tube](https://freetubeapp.io/#download) is a youtube client that can be installed windows, Mac OS and most other Linux distros.
it supports playback modification

[image: Free Tube Interface/w playback rate menu]

EDIT - added answer relevant to question, removed unneeded answer

Comment: The question mentions Windows as the OS.